# How often is the phrase “writ large” used?

Tags: word-usage

How often is the phrase “writ large” used? When did its use trend upwards?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! To help people better understand and answer your question, it'd help to edit your question to give more detail. For instance, why are you curious about "writ large"? What would make this relevant to others?  What research have you done to try to answer the question? ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) is a great guide to follow. Otherwise, good luck.

Comment: It *sounds* like a hangover from centuries ago, but in fact [it's an up-and-coming usage.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=writ+large&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) As to "how often", though - how long is a piece of string?

Comment: ...an incredibly high proportion of all written instances of ***writ large*** between 1800 and 1840 [follow some version of ***priest/s***.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*+writ+large&year_start=1800&year_end=1840&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) Make of that what you will (all instances of ***writ large*** back then don't amount to a can of beans compared to how often we use it today).

Comment: Can't you just plug it into Google Ngrams to see the trend?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Isn't the correct adjective to use with "beans" "hill" rather than "can", when you want to imply something insignificant? Despite hills often being larger than cans...

Comment: @tgdavies Like *beans*, both *hill* and *can* are nouns, not adjectives.

Comment: @tchrist Doh! But they're describing the the beans :-)

Comment: @tgdavies: You're [American,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+a+can+of+beans%2Cto+a+hill+of+beans&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3) obviously. We [Brits](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+a+can+of+beans%2Cto+a+hill+of+beans&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3) thought this one through a bit more carefully. If it don't amount to much, why compare it to a ***hill***? *He's no bigger than a flea!* - sure. But *He's no bigger than an elephant!* doesn't really work, does it? No more than a hill of beans, ditto.

Comment: @FumbleFingers it's a crazy world

Comment: @FumbleFingers - The phrase _priest writ large_ seems to be a reference to a line by Milton "New Presbyter is but old Priest writ large" (implying that Presbyterian clergy were no 'better' than the Catholic priests despised by Puritans).

Comment: @KateBunting: For all I know, Milton actually *coined* the collocation. But user 66974's usage chart strongly suggests to me that very few people who use it today (including me until yesterday) are likely to be aware of (or consciously *refer* to) that "original". It massively increased in popularity from late C19, but I don't suppose that reflected Anglophones in general suddenly being more interested in Milton's work. Personally, I think that ***writ*** not ***written*** choice gained much traction from late C19 *The moving finger writes; and, having **writ**, moves on.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Yes, I expect he did - I was just explaining your observation that so many early 19th century uses of the phrase mention priests!

Comment: @KateBunting: Well, like I said, I *didn't* know that original when writing my first comment - but as soon as I'd posted that comment, I saw user 66974's answer. And I've just confirmed that "original" status through the full OED (they explicitly identify Milton's "first use"). Note that many of the those *early* C19 usages involve various different capitalisations and plurals of ***priest/s***, which to my mind suggests those writers were indeed referencing, reflecting on, *and riffing off* Milton's original, but nowadays it's really just a "frozen form".

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52521/writ-large-writ-small-and-others

Answer (score 1):

According to [Google books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=writ%20large%2Cwrit%20small&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true) its usage has constantly increased in the last decades, especially from the 80’s.

Writ large:

> From writ (“(archaic) written”) + large, from the poem “On the New Forces of Conscience under the Long Parliament” in Poems, &c. upon Several Occasions (1673) by the English poet John Milton (1608–1674): “New Presbyter is but Old Priest writ large”; Milton was using the phrase in the sense “written more completely”.

(Wiktionary)

> Writ large should always be in reference to a specific noun, used after said noun as an appositive, and not as a verbal phrase (e.g., is writ large). It does not require the use of commas. Can also be used in the forms writ larger and writ largest.

(The Grammarist)

Comment: Haha - I was just extending my comment to point out how often the *older* usages involve ***priests***. And there you are flagging up the same point!Milton may have been responsible for that earlier influence, but clearly something else attracted us to it *again* many years later! I've never seen *writ **larger*** or *writ **largest*** though, and I'd tend to question the linguistic competence of anyone who used those versions non-facetiously today.